# Why is complex multiplication nearly as fast as integer multiplication in python?

Tags: python, performance, complex-numbers

I was under the impression that complex number multiplication takes longer than real number multiplication, since it requires [3 multiplications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Complex_multiplication_algorithm).

However I tried the following:

```
a, b = 3, 4
c, d = 5, 6
print(a*c - b*d, a*d + b*c)

e = 3+4j
f = 5+6j
print(e*f)

%timeit a*c - b*d
%timeit a*d + b*c
%timeit e*f
%timeit a*b
```

and got

```
-9 38
(-9+38j)
110 ns ± 0.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
102 ns ± 0.193 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
47.2 ns ± 0.942 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
43 ns ± 1.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

### Why is the complex number multiplication nearly as fast as the real number complication?

I understand that Python is a high level language, but this results still confuse me...

The only explanantion I can think of is that I am reaching such low speeds with both computations that somehow the bottleneck is not the computation itself but something else..

---

Here is the original question that I wanted to ask

---

I have this version of Discrete Fourier Transform that uses complex operations:

```
from math import e, pi, cos, sin, log2

def W(n, N):
    theta = n * -1 * 2 * pi / N
    return cos(theta) + 1j*sin(theta)

def dft(signal):
    N = len(signal)
    total = []
    for k in range(N):
        s = 0
        for n in range(N):
            s += signal[n] * W(n*k, N)
        total.append(s)
    return total
```

I also have this version of DFT that uses no complex operations and instead uses two real signals, as the imaginary part of the signal is encoded into a real array.

```
def Wri(n, N):
    theta = n * -1 * 2 * pi / N
    return cos(theta), sin(theta)

def dft_ri(signal_r, signal_i):
    N = len(signal_r)
    tr, ti = [], []
    for k in range(N):
        sr = 0
        si = 0
        for n in range(N):
            a = signal_r[n]
            b = signal_i[n]
            c, d = Wri(n*k, N)
            sr += a*c - b*d
            si += a*d + b*c
        tr.append(sr)
        ti.append(si)
    return tr, ti
```

Using the following complex signal

```
x = np.linspace(0, T, 1024)
def signal2(t):
    return np.where(np.logical_and((t%T>=0), (t%T<np.pi)), t%T+t%T*1j, np.pi+np.pi*1j)

s = list(signal2(x))
sr = list(np.real(s))
si = list(np.imag(s))
```

The two W's take the same amount of time roughly

```
%timeit W(8, 3)
%timeit Wri(8, 3)
```

outputs

```
464 ns ± 0.756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
424 ns ± 2.21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

However

```
%timeit dft(s)
%timeit dft_ri(sr, si)
```

outputs

```
935 ms ± 4.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.6 s ± 3.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Question

Why does the DFT without complex operations take nearly twice as long as the DFT with complex operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timings are almost 100% overhead. The actual hardware-level multiplication is only a tiny fraction of the cost either way.

Try it with NumPy arrays, which have far lower per-element overhead, and you see a different story:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.ones(10000)

In [3]: y = x.astype(complex)

In [4]: %timeit x*x
4.2 µs ± 51.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit y*y
16.6 µs ± 696 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [6]: z = x.astype(int)

In [7]: %timeit z*z
6.54 µs ± 1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

That's a per-element time in the vicinity of 1 nanosecond, while your timings are more like 40 to 100 per element.

---

The performance differences you're seeing with your FFT implementations are also due to overhead. Very little of your runtime is actually spent doing math.

Comment: I added the original question that I wanted to ask. Is this also due to overhead?
I could also ask the question about DFT separately if desired.

Comment: @charel-f: Yeah, that's also overhead. Use SciPy's FFT functions.

Comment: What really is the overhead due in the case of the DFT?

Comment: @charel-f: Object allocation, dynamic dispatch, the bytecode interpreter loop, etc. All the machinery involved in a JITless implementation of a highly dynamic programming language.